# Duplicate entry 1 for key 1 - no duplicates

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

Hi i'm trying to import a database to alive server and I keep getting this error message:

SQL query:

```
--
-- Dumping data for table `wp_2_comments`
--
INSERT INTO  `wp_2_comments` (  `comment_ID` ,  `comment_post_ID` ,  `comment_author` ,  `comment_author_email` , `comment_author_url` ,  `comment_author_IP` ,  `comment_date` ,  `comment_date_gmt` ,  `comment_content` ,  `comment_karma` , `comment_approved` ,  `comment_agent` ,  `comment_type` ,  `comment_parent` ,  `user_id` ) 
VALUES ( 1, 1,  'Mr WordPress',  '',  'http://www.kbee.co.za/',  '',  '2013-12-22 17:34:17',  '2013-12-22 17:34:17', 'Hi, this is a comment.\nTo delete a comment, just log in and view the post&#039;s comments. There you will have the option to edit or delete them.', 0,  '1',  '',  '', 0, 0 ) ;
```

MySQL said: Documentation

## 1062 - Duplicate entry '1' for key 1

Below is the structure of that particular table:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `wp_2_comments`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_2_comments` (
  `comment_ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `comment_post_ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `comment_author` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `comment_author_email` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `comment_author_url` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `comment_author_IP` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `comment_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `comment_date_gmt` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `comment_content` text NOT NULL,
  `comment_karma` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `comment_approved` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `comment_agent` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `comment_type` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `comment_parent` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`comment_ID`),
  KEY `comment_post_ID` (`comment_post_ID`),
  KEY `comment_approved_date_gmt` (`comment_approved`,`comment_date_gmt`),
  KEY `comment_date_gmt` (`comment_date_gmt`),
  KEY `comment_parent` (`comment_parent`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `wp_2_comments`
--

INSERT INTO `wp_2_comments` (`comment_ID`, `comment_post_ID`, `comment_author`, `comment_author_email`, `comment_author_url`, `comment_author_IP`, `comment_date`, `comment_date_gmt`, `comment_content`, `comment_karma`, `comment_approved`, `comment_agent`, `comment_type`, `comment_parent`, `user_id`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'Mr WordPress', '', 'http://www.kbee.co.za', '', '2013-12-22 17:34:17', '2013-12-22 17:34:17', 'Hi, this is a comment.\nTo delete a comment, just log in and view the post&#039;s comments. There you will have the option to edit or delete them.', 0, '1', '', '', 0, 0);
```

From what I have seen in other topics this could be because a table is being duplicated or or the primary key field is not auto incrementing. The structure in the table has the primary key field set to auto increment and I already tried dropping that particular table and trying to import again but I am finding no joy.

Comment: Is your primary key is identity ? if so yo need it to be reseed or Enable `Identity INSERT ON`

Comment: use `truncate tablename` and then insert values

Comment: What is already in your table ? `SELECT * FROM wp_2_comments`

Comment: Drop your table and import it again.

Answer (score 0):

For auto increment values even if you delete the row with value 1, the next value of auto increment col will be 2 and not 1.so truncate the table using

`truncate wp_2_comments`

and then try to insert the value which will start the count from 1.

also change this

```
 ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

to

```
 ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

First execute this query

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_2_comments` (
  `comment_ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `comment_post_ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `comment_author` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `comment_author_email` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `comment_author_url` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `comment_author_IP` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `comment_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `comment_date_gmt` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `comment_content` text NOT NULL,
  `comment_karma` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `comment_approved` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `comment_agent` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `comment_type` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `comment_parent` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`comment_ID`),
  KEY `comment_post_ID` (`comment_post_ID`),
  KEY `comment_approved_date_gmt` (`comment_approved`,`comment_date_gmt`),
  KEY `comment_date_gmt` (`comment_date_gmt`),
  KEY `comment_parent` (`comment_parent`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

then execute this query

```
truncate wp_2_comments
```

Comment: ok I tried what you said now i get this error message:             SQL query:

-- --------------------------------------------------------
--
-- Table structure for table `wp_2_comments`
--
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `wp_2_comments` TRUNCATE wp_2_comments;


MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'truncate wp_2_comments' at line 8

Comment: `truncate wp_2_comments` is a seperate command to truncate the table.use it after using the `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS.... `

Comment: where would I then put it? sorry I need a blow by blow, am new at this and thoroughly confused

Comment: first create the table using command `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS....` and then write `truncate wp_2_comments`

Comment: thats exactly what I did before I got that second error                          
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_2_comments` 
   truncate wp_2_comments; (
  `comment_ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `comment_post_ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `comment_author` tinytext NOT NULL,........

Comment: query1 => `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS wp_2_comments ( comment_ID bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, comment_post_ID bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', comment_author tinytext NOT NULL,....)`

Comment: query2 => `truncate wp_2_comments`

Comment: ok so truncate comes right before primary key or engine= innodb?

Comment: Yet another error SQL query:

ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT =1;


MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1' at line 1

Comment: i executed same query in my system it works.did you copied the same query or you typed some different query ?

Comment: I typed in truncate wp_2_comments right after the create command and before engine=innodb. Is there a way I can give you access to the export, in case you spot something I am missing

Comment: thats where you made it wrong.please check my answer and use same query posted by me

Comment: I'm sorry i dont understand. is this the answer you are talking about? 
query1 => CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS wp_2_comments ( comment_ID bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, comment_post_ID bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', comment_author tinytext NOT NULL,....)

Comment: exactly but add this `ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ` at the last

Comment: this is what I have at the moment    KEY `comment_approved_date_gmt` (`comment_approved`,`comment_date_gmt`),
  KEY `comment_date_gmt` (`comment_date_gmt`),
  KEY `comment_parent` (`comment_parent`)
) ;
truncate `wp_2_comments` ;
 ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

Comment: and this is the error I get when i try to upload   SQL query:

ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT =1;


MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1' at line 1

Comment: `ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT =1; ` is not a separate query. it was part of `create table`. check whether you have got a table created if yes then you carry on with truncate command